# Swap function in prolog, infinite loop

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am trying to create a swap function in `prolog` but I ended up with an `infinite loop`, I tried to debug it using `trace()`

An example of this function is swap(4, 3, ["You", "Are", "Awesome", "thank", "You"], SwappedList)

With the output being

> ["You", "Are", "thank", "Awesome", "You"]

In the trace output, it is showing that the problem is in the delete as it is `failing` and `redoes` the `split`

```
/* Getting the nth element of the list*/

n_thelement(1, [Head|_], Head).
n_thelement(N, [_|Tail], Item):-
    NewN is N-1,
    n_thelement(NewN, Tail, Item).

/* Deleting the element of the desired Nth element*/

delete(X, [X|Tail], Tail).
delete(X, [Head|Tail], [Head|Item]):-
    delete(X, Tail, Item).

/* Adding the deleted element to the beginning of the list*/

append([], Element, Element).
append([Head], Element, [Head|Element]).

swap(X, X, List, List).

swap(X, Y, List, NList):-
    n_thelement(X, List, Num1),
    n_thelement(Y, List, Num2),
    split(X, List, B1, A1),
    delete(Num1, A1, L1),
    append([Num2], L1, NList1),
    append(B1, NList1, NList2),
    split(Y, NList2, B2, A2),
    delete(Num2, A2, L2),
    append([Num1], L2, NList3),
    append(B2, NList3, NList).
    
split(1, [Head|Tail], Head, Tail).

split(N, [Old_List|New_List], Old_List, New_List):-
    NewN is N -1,
    split(NewN, _, Old_List, New_List).
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem statement correctly, given to indices into a list, M and N such that M < N and M and N are both valid indices into the list, you want to swap the elements at those indices.

I would first make the indices zero-relative instead of 1-relative as that makes the math a little easier.

So, you want to break up the list into 5 pieces, 3 of which are themselves lists of any length and two of which are the list entries to be swapped:

- `As`: The lead-in prefix of the list. It is of length M.
- `B`: The 1st item to be swapped.
- `Cs`: The middle segment of the list. It is of length N - (M+1).
- `D`: The 2nd item to be swapped.
- `Es`: The suffix/remainder of the list. It is of any length.

`append/3` is useful for deconstruction and reconstruction of lists, making the actual swap easy. You have 3 cases.

- First, the special case of both indices being the same, in which case, there is no work to do:

  ```
  swap( M, M, Ls, Ls ).
  ```
- Second, the case of the indices being out of order, in which case we just recursively swap them to put them in order:

  ```
  swap( M, N, Ls, Rs ) :- M > N, swap(N,M,Ls,Rs).
  ```
- Third, the general case:

  ```
  swap( M, N, Ls, Rs ) :-      % if the 2 indices differ
    M < N,                     % - and are in order
    M >= 0,                    % - and M is greater than or equal to zero
    N >= 0,                    % - and N is greater than or equal to zero
    X is N - (M+1),            % - compute the length of the middle segment
    length( As, M  ),          % - construct an empty, unbound list of length M, the length of the prefix
    length( Cs, X ),           % - and construct an empty, unbound list of that length
    append( As, [B|T1], Ls),   % - get the prefix (As) and the first item (B) to be swapped
    append( Cs, [D|Es], T1),   % - get the middle segment (Cs), the second item (D) to be swapped, and the suffix (Es)
    append( As, [D|Cs], T2),   % - concatenate As, D, and Cs, then...
    append( T2, [B|Es], Rs )   % - concatenate that with B and the suffix
    .                          % Easy!
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a predicate to **replace** the *i*-th item of the list for another:

```
replace(Index, [Old|Rest], [New|Rest], Old, New) :- Index == 0, !.
replace(Index, [First|Rest], [First|NewRest], Old, New) :-
   Index > 0,
   Previous is Index - 1,
   replace(Previous, Rest, NewRest, Old, New).
```

Examples:

```
?- replace(1, [a,b,c,d,e], List1, Old1, x).
List1 = [a, x, c, d, e],
Old1 = b.

?- replace(1, [a,b,c,d,e], List1, Old1, New1).
List1 = [a, New1, c, d, e],
Old1 = b.

?- replace(4, [a,b,c,d,e], List2, Old2, New2).
List2 = [a, b, c, d, New2],
Old2 = e.
```

Then, using this predicate, you can define:

```
swap(I, J, OldList, NewList) :-
   replace(I, OldList, List, X, Y),
   replace(J, List, NewList, Y, X).
```

Examples:

```
?- swap(3, 2, ["You", "Are", "Awesome", "thank", "You"], L).
L = ["You", "Are", "thank", "Awesome", "You"].

?- swap(1, 4, [a,b,c,d,e], L).
L = [a, e, c, d, b].

?- swap(0, 3, [a,b,c,d,e], L).
L = [d, b, c, a, e].

?- swap(1, 0, [a,b,c,d,e], L).
L = [b, a, c, d, e].

?- swap(2, 2, [a,b,c,d,e], L).
L = [a, b, c, d, e].

?- swap(3, 9, [a,b,c,d,e], L).
false.
```